# Querystring encoding issue

Tags: c#, query-string

I am facing one problem while storing a querystring value in a variable.
My url is something like shown below:

```
http://localhost:1372/testapp/default.aspx?Search=%family%
```

Below is what I tried:

```
string result = Request.QueryString["Search"].ToString();
```

When I tried to save the querystring search in variable its taking value as  `�mily%` .

How can I get value of search parameter as family?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does that query string come from? It is clearly wrong ... you need to `UrlEncode` the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The query string parameters have to get URL-encoded. The problem ist th % character which is used for URL encoding, so it has to get encoded itself.

'%' becomes '%25'

Which means, the whole URL becomes:

```
http://localhost:1372/testapp/default.aspx?Search=%25family%25
```

your can use `HttpUtitlity.UrlEncode`

Comment: I tried this but its giving me value as '%ef%bf%bdmily%25'

Answer (score 1):

In Parent Page Encode query string this way

```
public static sting Encode(string sData)
{
return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sData);
}
```

Now pass this encoded query string to your parent page & on Parent page decode that query string by following function. I assume that encoded query string name is sData & its passed from parent page to child page

```
public static string Decode()
{
string dSData = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["sData"].ToString());
return dsData;
}
```

I think you have idea about how to pass query string from parent to child page

try [this solution](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/urlEncoding/) for more .